# Multi User OS on AWS or Azure?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, operating-system, cloud

I was little curious to know whether there exist a cloud service (AWS or azure ) that provide multiple user access to an single os instance simultaneously?

Scenario which I want to achieve - A teacher and its student are accessing a Cloud OS service [through internet] and anything demonstration teacher is showing on OS , students can see simultaneously from their personal desktop.
Is This possible ? OS can Windows/Ubuntu.

Comment: Are you looking for some thing like [Sharing Remote Desktop Sessions](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Horizon-Client-for-Windows/2012/horizon-client-windows-installation/GUID-99D37183-B4F9-4C40-95BA-FFB6DB746AA2.html) ?

Comment: ya something similar to that ....but not sure where to start ..i am bit beginner ..is there exist a straightforward tutorial? [can the same be done with aws or any cloud service provider]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: I misinterpreted your title. You're asking for two people, same account, seeing the same updates. You can still do separate `ssh` sessions on Linux for the same account and then both use `tmux` to attach to the same session. Then one of you will be able to see the other making changes in the same `tmux` session. I just tried it on my own AWS instance. Also, see [here](https://www.howtoforge.com/sharing-terminal-sessions-with-tmux-and-screen) for how to do it.

---

Using ssh access when you first create an AWS instance, you can create new users on Ubuntu or Centos. Then multiple people can access the instance through `ssh` with their own user accounts. I imagine it's the same with Azure or any other cloud provider, as well as any OS that supports multiple user `ssh` sessions. I've personally done it with multiple `ssh` sessions, some `root`, some the `centos` default user.

Comment: Can u please specify the exact AWS service to use like  Windows on Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (EC2) or something similar

Comment: I use Amazon EC2 and then use the Centos7 AMI. But like I said, I imagine it works for any linux variation and I'm sure other OSes, I just haven't tried those specifically.

Comment: Check out my edited answer with the share screen feature you're looking for for Linux.

Comment: @jiyasingh Did this answer solve your issue? If this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. However, there is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Thanks for helping in those times ...i completely forgot to  appreciate your valuable answer . Hope next time i would be more alert to respect back to the community  which helped me in hard times.

Comment: No worries, glad to hear it helped!